# MPI_Get is slow with structs containing padding

Tags: c++, mpi

I recently had to code an MPI application where I send std::vector contents in a distributed environment. In order to try different approaches I coded both 1-sided and 2-sided point-to-point communication schemes, the first one uses MPI_Window and MPI_Get, the second one uses MPI_SendRecv.

I had a hard time figuring out why my implementation with MPI_Get was between 10 and 100 times slower, and I finally found out that MPI_Get is abnormally slow when one tries to send custom datatypes including padding.

Here is a short example, where I send a struct {double, int} (12 bytes of data + 4 bytes of padding) vs a struct {double, int, int} (16 bytes of data, 0 bytes of padding) with both MPI_SendRecv and MPI_Get, and the results I got.

I run it with Open MPI 4.1.2 and with intel MPI 2021.6 with the same results (with intel the communication only happens if np > 2).

Is this result normal? Do I have any solution other than adding garbage at the end of the struct to avoid padding?

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

struct Test1
{
    double a;
    int b;
};

bool operator!=(const Test1 x, const Test1 y) {return x.a != y.a or x.b != y.b;};

struct Test2
{
    double a;
    int b, c;
};

bool operator!=(const Test2 x, const Test2 y) {return x.a != y.a or x.b != y.b or x.c != y.c;};

const int maxWorldSize = 8;

//each proc sends an array of sz elements of type T to every other proc with SendRecv
template<class T, int sz>
double SendRecv(int world_size, int world_rank, MPI_Datatype dt)
{
    T sendBuffer[sz], recvBuffer[maxWorldSize*sz];

    T element;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Test1>) element = {1., 2};
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Test2>) element = {1., 2, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        sendBuffer[i] = element;
    }

    auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int offset = 1; offset < world_size; offset++)
    {
        int dest = (world_rank + offset)%world_size;
        int source = (world_rank - offset + world_size)%world_size;
        MPI_Status s;

        MPI_Sendrecv(sendBuffer, sz, dt, dest, 0, recvBuffer + source*sz, sz, dt, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);
    }
    auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    //ensure the result is used somewhere
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++)
    {
        if (i != world_rank)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            {
                if (recvBuffer[i*sz + j] != element) std::cout << "Problem" << std::endl;
            }
        } 
    }

    return std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count();
}

//each proc sends an array of sz elements of type T to every other proc with Window and Get
template<class T, int sz>
double Get(int world_size, int world_rank, MPI_Datatype dt)
{
    T sendBuffer[sz], recvBuffer[maxWorldSize*sz];

    T element;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Test1>) element = {1., 2};
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Test2>) element = {1., 2, 3};

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        sendBuffer[i] = element;
    }

    MPI_Win window;
    MPI_Info infos;

    MPI_Info_create(&infos);
    MPI_Win_create(sendBuffer, sz*sizeof(T), sizeof(T), infos, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &window);
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

    auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int offset = 1; offset < world_size; offset++)
    {
        int source = (world_rank - offset + world_size)%world_size;
        MPI_Get(recvBuffer + source*sz, sz, dt, source, 0, sz, dt, window);
    }
    auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
    MPI_Win_free(&window);
    MPI_Info_free(&infos);

    //ensure the result is used somewhere
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++)
    {
        if (i != world_rank)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sz; j++)
            {
                if (recvBuffer[i*sz + j] != element) std::cout << "Problem" << std::endl;
            }
        } 
    }

    return std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int world_size, world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    if (world_size > maxWorldSize) std::cout << "SendRecv and Get function will seg fault if world_size > " << maxWorldSize << std::endl;
    if (world_size == 1) std::cout << "MPI_Window won't work if world_size == 1" << std::endl;
    assert(world_size <= maxWorldSize && world_size > 1);

    const int size = 1e6;

    MPI_Datatype datatype1;
    int array_of_blocklengths1[2] = {1, 1};
    MPI_Aint array_of_displacements1[2] = {0, 8};
    MPI_Datatype array_of_types1[2] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, array_of_blocklengths1, array_of_displacements1, array_of_types1, &datatype1);
    MPI_Type_commit(&datatype1);
    
    //send {double, int} with MPI_SendRecv
    auto time = SendRecv<Test1, size>(world_size, world_rank, datatype1);
    if (world_rank == 0) std::cout << "{double, int} SendRecv : " << time << " s" << std::endl;

    //send {double, int} with MPI_Window and MPI_Get
    time = Get<Test1, size>(world_size, world_rank, datatype1);
    if (world_rank == 0) std::cout << "{double, int} Get : " << time << " s" << std::endl;

    MPI_Datatype datatype2;
    int array_of_blocklengths2[2] = {1, 2};
    MPI_Aint array_of_displacements2[2] = {0, 8};
    MPI_Datatype array_of_types2[2] = {MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, array_of_blocklengths2, array_of_displacements2, array_of_types2, &datatype2);
    MPI_Type_commit(&datatype2);
    
    //send {double, int, int} with MPI_SendRecv
    time = SendRecv<Test1, size>(world_size, world_rank, datatype2);
    if (world_rank == 0) std::cout << "{double, int, int} SendRecv : " << time << " s" << std::endl;

    //send {double, int, int} with MPI_Window and MPI_Get
    time = Get<Test1, size>(world_size, world_rank, datatype2);
    if (world_rank == 0) std::cout << "{double, int, int} Get : " << time << " s" << std::endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The results :

```
mpirun -np 4 ./compareGetWithSendRecv 
{double, int} SendRecv : 0.0303547 s
{double, int} Get : 1.9196 s
{double, int, int} SendRecv : 0.0164659 s
{double, int, int} Get : 0.0147757 s
```

Comment: My suspicion is that the non-padded type is optimized to one large memcpy/whatever while the padded type tries to not read/write the padding, thereby splitting into multiple memcpys. The suspicious part is this should also affect the prebuilt type `MPI_DOUBLE_INT`. Can you check whether that is also slow?

Comment: Interesting that this happens with 2 MPI implementations that don't share a common codebase. Is this on one node? Can you run it on more than one node? I would suspect that this only shows on a single node.

Comment: @Homer512 MPI_DOUBLE_INT gives exactly the same results as my datatype1. MPI_Get is between 10 and 100 times slower than MPI_SendRecv.

Comment: I think I traced it from OpenMPI's `MPI_Get` to [`_copy_content_same_ddt`](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/main/opal/datatype/opal_datatype.h), which does indeed not do a continuous `memcpy` if the extent is bigger than the size (meaning: padding). But I've not yet been able to do the same for the send receive path. Could also be a red herring

Comment: Unless your hardware as native support for padded data, and your MPI library knows how to use it, I am not surprised there is a massive drop in performance since a one-sided operation does not translate any more into a single rdma operation. If the padding contains data you do not care about, you'd rather put/get contiguous chunks of memory (e.g. the data plus the padding).

Comment: In order to give a quick answer to any reader of this post, one solution for padding is to add n `MPI_BYTE` at the end of the struct, that means MPI is now allowed to copy the padding bytes and won't split the copy into one copy per element. To make sure this won't depend on the hardware, I preferred to declare the entire struct as n = sizeof(myStruct) `MPI_BYTE`. I also noticed very bad performance of `MPI_Get` when the `MPI_Datatype` is built with strictly positive displacements (for example a `MPI_Type_indexed(...)`), so one really should also use contiguous data with `MPI_Get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an artifact of how MPI RMA is implemented.  I have not done a precise root cause but I know enough of how Open-MPI 4.x implements RMA to provide a reasonable theory here.

The reason `MPI_Sendrecv` is fast both ways is that it uses the datatypes engine to pack and unpack data.  This has an overhead but it is limited by the bandwidth of the CPU, which is usually faster than the network.  The overhead you see - 0.03 versus 0.016 - makes sense.

`MPI_Get` is not using the datatypes engine but rather sending every 12-byte struct separately, because using the datatypes engine would require processing on the remote side, which is an active message, and that gets in the way of RDMA, which Open-MPI is trying to use in RMA (RDMA is often a good thing in RMA).

When you add the extra element, your 16-byte structs form a contiguous slab of memory, so the operation can proceed as one, which is ideal from a bandwidth perspective.

The conclusion to draw here is that you should pad your structs so the size (`MPI_Type_size`) and extent (`MPI_Type_get_extent`) are the same, so that an array of them can be transferred efficiently.